# Double Integral Equality

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $F(t)$ be the primitive function of $f(t)$ , with $F(a)=0$ , why is it that:  $$\int_{a}^{t} \, \left(\int_{a}^{u} \, f(s) \, ds \right) \, du = \int_{a}^{t} \, (t-s) \, f(s) \, ds.$$

Comment: Integration by parts: $$
\int_a^tF(u)\,du=-\int_a^tuf(u)\,du+F(t)t=-\int_a^tuf(u)\,du+\int_a^ttf(u)\,du\,.
$$

Comment: Without mentioning $F$, change the order of integration.

Comment: By the way, this already appears numerous times on this site. Perhaps do some searching before posting?